# how to access this file from outside the project

Tags: c#, class

this is my code and i want to access this method from another project file, another project is added and everything is working fine except this method, when i created a new class and pasted that code on it, it says:

**'iEndRecord'is a fields but is used like a type**

```
    private void GetNoOfRows()
    {
        int iTotalRecords = ((DataTable)(grdCrew.DataSource)).Rows.Count;
        int iEndRecord = grdCrew.PageSize * (grdCrew.PageIndex + 1);
        int iStartsRecods = iEndRecord - grdCrew.PageSize;

        if (iEndRecord > iTotalRecords)
        {
            iEndRecord = iTotalRecords;
        }

        if (iStartsRecods == 0)
        {
            iStartsRecods = 1;
        }
        if (iEndRecord == 0)
        {
            iEndRecord = iTotalRecords;
        }
        lblCount.Text = iStartsRecods + " to " + iEndRecord.ToString() + " of " + iTotalRecords.ToString();
        DataBind();
    }
```

P.S. this is complete code, this is just a method to call a function for counting rows, its working fine inside file, but i was trying to put it on one external file so that i don't have to write the same code in all files again and again

Comment: post the whole class ...

Answer (score 0):

and the namespaces?
Im pretty sure that you forget add they

Comment: no its not about namespace, all other files are working fine in that project, it looks like i cant write this code on a cs file casue its giving me error on "grdView"(which is the Gridview name) and gives error "the name '' does not exist in the current context"..